# Connect Four: Help Using JQuery in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to programming and am trying to make a simple, Html/CSS/Javascript/JQuery Connect Four game. Here is
[what i have so far.](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshKono/mgje9zye/3/)

Only problem is you can't stack tokens on top of each other! This Connect four game sucks ; )!

Inside the `dropToken()` function, I am trying to create a for loop with an if statement to find if the space I am trying to put the token on is white, or else, go up one `tr` by using the `var i` counter in the for loop.

```
function dropToken(obj, column)
{            
    for (var i == 6; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if ($('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(' + column + ')').css("background-color") == "white")
        {
            $('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(' + column + ')').css("background-color", playerTurn);
        }
    }
    if (playerTurn == "Red")
    {
        playerTurn = "Blue"
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "Blue";   
    }
    else
    {
        playerTurn = "Red"
        obj.style.backgroundColor = "Red"; 
    }
}
```

However, this code makes the program [not work.](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshKono/mgje9zye/4/)

Comment: Tried utilizing `rgb(n,n,n)` instead of color names ?

Comment: You need to use `if (element.css("background-color") == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")` to compare colors. It may or may not be browser dependant .. not sure yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/f7hpoyfj/1/

You need to use `if (element.css("background-color") == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")` to compare colors. It may or may not be browser dependant .. not sure yet

Also, see how I created the loop - you did not use `i` in your previous function which I think is a mistake, as you effectively compared the same element over and over again.

```
for (var i = 7; i > 1; i--)
{
    var element = $('table tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(' + column + ')');
    if (element.css("background-color") == "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)" || element.css("background-color") == "transparent" || element.css("background-color") == "white")
    {
        element.css("background-color", playerTurn);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works great! If you don't mind me asking, what does the break code mean?

Comment: `break` means to exit the closest loop (the `for` loop). You only want to modify one block, so once you do so, you want to exit the loop to avoid modifying the rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

For something a little more compact and jQUery like:

```js
$(".topRow td").click(function(){
    var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    
    
    var activePlayer = $(this).closest("table").data("activeplayer"); 
    //Get First available slot
    var cells = $("table tr td:nth-child(" + (col+1)  +")");
    var cell;
    for(var i = cells.length -1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        if($(cells[i]).data("token") == undefined)
        {
            cell = cells[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    
    $(cell).data("token", activePlayer).addClass(activePlayer);      
   
    
    //Toggle Active Player 
    activePlayer = activePlayer == "red" ? "blue" : "red";
    $(this).closest("table").toggleClass("red blue").data("activeplayer", activePlayer);
    

});
```

```css
table {
    border-bottom: 4px solid black;
    border-left: 4px solid black;
    border-right: 4px solid black; 
}

td {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

table.blue .topRow td:hover, td.blue
{
background-color:blue;    
}

table.red .topRow td:hover, td.red
{
background-color:red;    
}




.topRow td {
    border: 2px solid white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-activeplayer="blue" class="blue">
        <tr class="topRow">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="resetBoard()">Empty Tokens</button>
```

I'll leave it up to you for the clear all. Using data may make it easier to determine "win" conditions later.